# Problem with wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress installation was fine, but when I try to download themes or plugins I get message:
Installation failed: Download failed.
And I don't get any explanation for that.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Check that the user the webserver runs on (www-data) has write permissions on the theme/plugin folder.

Comment: You need something like this: `chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/wordpress/wp-content`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress).

Comment: This doesn't help, unfortunately.